# Phaser.js Basic p2 physic robot

Tags: javascript, physics, game-physics, phaser-framework

I want to make a very basic robot that rotate a arm around it axis like the image bellow [jsfiddle coffeescript version](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld3suwya/) , i've tried with P2 joints, groups, childs, and had no success, could anyone help with this ? :)

```js
'use strict';
var game, mainState;

game = new Phaser.Game(320, 480, Phaser.AUTO, 'space');

mainState = {
  preload: function() {
game.load.image('body', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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')
    game.load.image('arms', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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')
    game.load.image('ground', 'data:image/png;base64,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')
  },
  create: function() {
        var groundCollisionGroup, robotCollisionGroup;
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
this.chest = game.add.sprite(29, 53, 'body');
this.arms = game.add.sprite(8, 53, 'arms');
this.ground = game.add.sprite(320, 70, 'ground');
game.physics.p2.enable([this.chest, this.arms, this.ground]);
robotCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
groundCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
this.ground.body["static"] = true;
this.ground.body.setCollisionGroup(groundCollisionGroup);
this.ground.body.collides(robotCollisionGroup);
this.chest.body.debug = true;
this.chest.body.setCollisionGroup(robotCollisionGroup);
this.chest.body.collides(groundCollisionGroup);
this.arms.body.debug = true;
this.arms.body.setCollisionGroup(robotCollisionGroup);
this.arms.body.collides(groundCollisionGroup);
this.ground.reset(game.world.centerX, game.world.height);
this.chest.reset(game.world.centerX, game.world.height - 100);
this.arms.reset(game.world.centerX, game.world.height - 100);
game.physics.p2.gravity.y = 600;
this.chest.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
this.arms.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
this.arms.body.data.gravityScale = 0;
this.constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(this.chest, [-14, -26.5], this.arms, [-4, 28]);
return this.cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  },
  update: function() {
      if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
  this.arms.body.rotateLeft(60);
} else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
  this.arms.body.rotateRight(60);
} else {

}
  },
  render: function() {
    return game.config.enableDebug = true;
  }
};

game.state.add('start', mainState);

game.state.start('start');

//# sourceMappingURL=application.js.map
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.6/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="space"></div>
```

[image]

[image]